# Tengo una lista en una variable que no logro mostrar en el template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Mis modelos para este trabajo logra conseguir a través de una iteración dentro del modelo Producto, y luego se guarda en una variable una lista de la tabla Total con el id = id_producto. Y a esa lista agregar a través de .aggregate la sumatoria de su campo (en este caso cant)

```
class Producto (models.Model):
TIPO_ACTIVO = 1
TIPO_INACTIVO = 0
TIPO_CHOICES = {
         (TIPO_ACTIVO, 'Activo'),
         (TIPO_INACTIVO, 'Inactivo'),             
     }
tipo  = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
fecha_expiracion = models.DateField(null=True, blank = True, default='12/12/2020')
cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
estado = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = TIPO_CHOICES, null=True, default=True) 


donacion = models.ForeignKey(Donacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
#programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}/{}'.format(self.descripcion, self.tipo )


class Total(models.Model):
cant = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 
programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)



def __str__(self):
    return '{}/ {}/ {} '.format(self.producto.descripcion, self.tipo, self.cant)
```

Luego de los modelos establecidos llamo a través de una vista un template, con todo los productos con cierto rango en la fecha de expiración, y a su vez agrego la variable en la cual estará la suma de la lista total que tendrán el id_producto en comun.

```
@login_required
def productos_expiran (request, *args, **kwargs):
template = 'donacion/productos_expiran.html'

productos = Producto.objects.filter(fecha_expiracion__range= (datetime.now(),  datetime.now() + timedelta (days = 365)))

for producto in productos:
    id_total = Total.objects.filter(producto__id=producto.id)
    j = id_total.aggregate(suma = Sum('cant'))



data = {
'productos': productos, 
}
return render(request,template, data)
```

Hasta el momento se encuentra impresa en el cmd la variable stock de la función productos a expirar, como se puede ver en la imagen

[image: se encuentra imprimida en el cmd la variable stock de la funcion productos a expirar]

Ahora, cuando quiere mostrar esta variable en el template.

```
{% block content %}
```

```
    <div class="row  justify-content-center ">
        <div class=" col-md-12  col-sm-12  col-lg-10 p-4 " >

    <h3 class="page-header text-primary">PRODUCTOS POR EXPIRAR EN LAS PROXIMAS FECHAS :</h3>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="retornar" href="{% url 'donacion:donaciones' %}" class="btn bold ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-info">Retornar </a>

    <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">


    <div class="row  ">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md table-responsive-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead class="">
                                    <tr class="">
                                        <th class="text-center ">CATEGORIA</th>
                                        <th class="text-center ">NOMBRES</th> 
                                        <th class="text-center ">CANTIDAD</th>
                                        <th class="text-center ">STOCK</th>
                                         <th class="text-center ">FECHA</th> 

                                         <th class="text-center ">ACCION</th>  

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                    {%  for producto in productos %}
                                            {% if producto.estado == 1 %}

                                             <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ producto.tipo.nombre }}

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                {{ producto.descripcion }}
                                            </td>


                                            <td class="text-center">

                                                {{ producto.cantidad}}


                                            </td>
                                             <td class="text-center" >

                                                <strong> 
                                                 {{stock}}
                                                </strong>
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="text-center">

                                                {{ producto.fecha_expiracion }}

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                            <a href="{% url 'donacion:inactivar' producto.id %}" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-danger text-light" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="QUITAR DE LISTA" ><i class="fas fa-times"></i> </a>




                                             </td>


                                            {% else %}
                                            {% endif %}

                                            </tr>
                                  {% endfor %}      


                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

```
{% endblock %}
```

Lo único que consigo es traer el último dato de la lista y no todos datos iterados como se muestra en el cmd.

Comment: necesito poder mostrar lo que esta en la variable al template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Producto (models.Model):
TIPO_ACTIVO = 0
TIPO_INACTIVO = 1
TIPO_CHOICES = {
         (TIPO_ACTIVO, 'Activo'),
         (TIPO_INACTIVO, 'Inactivo'),             
     }
tipo  = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
fecha_expiracion = models.DateField(null=True, blank = True, default='12/12/2020')
cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
estado = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = TIPO_CHOICES, null=True, default=TIPO_ACTIVO)
stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


donacion = models.ForeignKey(Donacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}/{}'.format(self.descripcion, self.tipo )
```

creando un campo en el modelo de producto, deajndolo en blanco de default.
conseguimos agregar nuestro resultado de la variable stock dentro del campo nuevo de producto.

Answer (score 0):

No estas enviendo nunca la variable 'stock' al template. Por eso no la puedes visualizar.

Haz lo siguiente, dentro del bucle for agregar el stock de cada producto:

```
for producto in productos:
    id_total = Total.objects.filter(producto__id=producto.id)
    j = id_total.aggregate(suma = Sum('cant'))
    stock = (j['suma'])
    print(stock)
    producto = producto.as_json()  #transforma cada obj en un json para agregarle info adicional
    producto['stock'] = stock  #Esta linea es la agregada
```

Y luego en el template,

```
<td class="text-center" >
    <strong>
         {{producto.stock}}  #Esta linea es la modificada
    </strong>
</td>
```

Comment: si eh intentado la variable  {{stock}} en el template y como se puede ver en la imagen tengo lo que necesito en la variable de la funcion en la cual ya estoy iterando en el modelo Producto.
ahora cuando en el template muestro la variable que se vuelve a iterar en productos  me causa que traiga solo el ultimo dato de este diccionario

Comment: ademas hizo lo que me suguieres pero no logro conseguir mucho me sigue mostrando el ultimo dato. por que estoy dentro de una doble iteracion una en la funcion y se vuelve a iterar en el template...

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear un método en tu modelo, siempre y cuando no reciba ningún parámetro y llamarlo directamente en el template ej:

```
class Producto (models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    def stock(self):
        ....
        ....
```

y en tu template dentro del iterados de productos

```
{{ producto.stock }}
```